# after apt-get upgrade monitors freeze whenever I change something in 'displays'

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors, freeze, external-monitor

If I open **Displays** and change anything, from resolution, to disabling or enabling one of the monitors, my monitors freeze as soon as I click <kbd>Apply</kbd>

Sometimes I can still see the mouse movements. I can then go into <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to do `sudo service lightdm restart` in order to unfreeze the monitors. Of course, the changes are not applied.

This is  a freshly installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 on an ASUS k56, with an external monitor. It worked perfectly until this upgrade today.

I am using bumblebee with nvidia. They work just fine since I can run optirun glxspheres64 and play CSGO on Steam. And I could make changes to the displays w/o it freezing. The freezing started **after** this upgrade.

```
$ uname -a
Linux k56 3.13.0-46-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 26 18:52:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm thinking it's one of the packages mentioned in this upgrade log: https://gist.github.com/cristianmtr/6d049e4b8c8d2c695cdf

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:0153] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] [10de:0fdf] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6627]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA

**VGA**: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

And:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f install
"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."
```

I'm thinking it's [this bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1314871). Apparently there are quite a lot of people affected by it.

Comment: You're using a bit older kernel for 14.04 current is `3.16.0-30-generic`. What does `sudo apt-get -f install` tell you? and please add the output `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2`

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` my bad....

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish see edit

Comment: you got hybrid graphics did you try using Bumblebee? read more here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics or try Bumblebee solution here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I am using bumblebee w/ nvidia. And they're working fine. I can play CSGO on Steam just fine.

Comment: sometimes there's incompatibilities with video drivers after kernel upgrade so it needs the driver to be reinstalled again. Still not sure why are you using older `kernel` version.

Comment: I tried updating to 3.16 but after reboot neither the mouse nor the keyboard (usb, external) were recognized. Neither was the external monitor or the wired connection. I re-installed Ubuntu completely. I think it was 3 16 31.

Comment: when you upgraded to 3.16 you had to install or reinstall Bumblebee again. Did you do so? Check troubleshootings and driver updates at Bumblee source https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: fixed now. see last edit.

Comment: don't add too much similar PPAs to your `sources.list` esp. those relating the video drivers it doesn't make it better only worse if stick to Bumblebee then go with it! :) And please provide a solution to this question what you did to solve your issue in answer section.

Comment: @cristianmtr use `sudo service lightdm start`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's fixed now. I removed `xorg-edgers-ppa` from `sources.list.d` directory:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list.save
```

or better:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Then ran an update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot `X`:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Now I can edit the display settings to my heart's desire! Thanks for the help.